# How do I update the model for a WebGrid using Ajax?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a WebGrid that allows me to update the data source with Ajax. The data source is assigned a List<> containing a model I created to hold the data. The WebGrid populates correctly and I have no problem sorting using the header of the WebGrid or paging.
The code for the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestDataModel.Models.TestData>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Website";

    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", ajaxUpdateCallback: "callBack");
    grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: 10);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
                  tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                  headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                  alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                  rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                  mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                  firstText: "<< First",
                  previousText: "< Prev",
                  nextText: "Next >",
                  lastText: "Last >>",
                  columns: grid.Columns("This is a place holder,
                                         I have a lot of columns"
                  ));
}
<div>
    <br />
    <p>
        Page Number: <input type="text" name="pageNumber" id="pageNumber" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="pageNumberButton" id="pageNumberButton" value="Page" />
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pageNumberButton").click(function () {

            var pageNumber = $("#pageNumber").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Test")?pageNumber=' + pageNumber,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#grid").html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

The bottom script tag is the ajax call that I'm trying to use to update the WebGrid. All that the "GetData" does is create a list pulling data from an SQL server and returns `Json(testData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`. 
Code for Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string pageNumber)
        {
            List<TestData> testData = new List<TestData>();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageNumber))
            {
                testData = Data.Data.TestDataGet();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var pageInt = Convert.ToInt32(pageNumber);
                    List<ParameterSQL> parameter = new List<ParameterSQL>();
                    parameter.Add(new ParameterSQL { Name = "@pageOffset", Value = pageInt });
                    testData = Data.Data.TestDataGet(parameter);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
            return Json(testData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The error that I'm experiencing is when I push the button the WebGrid disappears entirely. The reason that I need to be able to update the WebGrid data source is because my table is millions of lines long and I'm only grabbing them a few thousand at a time. Once the user reaches the end of the of the list I want them to be able to load more using a SQL query that I already have working. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I am discovering now that in the AJAX call, it is not actually calling the GetData method in the controller. I put a break at the beginning and it never hits it.

Comment: It looks like your AJAX call is returning JSON that you are inserting into your HTML. You need to reproduce the table rows with the new data as shown in [this example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Client-Side-Paging-in-WebGrid-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)